# if-else statement not working correctly in while loop

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm not sure what exactly I'm doing wrong here. I'd like to get an extra link if a user is an admin, and the link should be void if the user is a member. But I get the extra link that should be for admins only even if I'm logged in as a member. What am I doing wrong in my code?

```
$connect=mysqli_connect("$db_server", "$db_user", "$db_password", "$db_database");
$query="SELECT admin FROM `$table_members`";
$result=mysqli_query($connect, $query);
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $admin = $row['admin'];
    if ($admin=="Administrator") {
        echo "<a href=\"admin.php\">Admin Panel</a>";
    }
    else {
        echo "";
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: print the value of `$admin` before the if loop and see what it prints. I doubt, you are missing `where` condition in your query, so it fetches all result including the admin record, so you are getting it.

Comment: It prints both :o *dies*

Comment: You are using `mysqli_fetch_assoc` for grabbing that value for admin, but you aren't passing any kind of `WHERE` clause to your `SELECT` under the `$table_members`. Try `var_dump`'ing your `$result` and seeing what you are actually getting for the SQL.

Comment: I've tried a lot, including `WHERE admin='Administrator'`, and other switching but nada... @_@

Comment: echo $query; before execute and copy paste it into directly in database and check that query is correct or not @Aki

Comment: remove double quotes `mysqli_connect("$db_server", "$db_user", "$db_password", "$db_database")`

Comment: waiting for your response

Comment: @devpro Thank you, I got it working by identifying `WHERE email` as a logged in user.

Comment: @Aki: i think u selected wrong answer as acceptance.

Comment: @devpro I've selected Pavneet's answer.. -reselecting-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see any query which make the difference b/w admin and member, your code simply retrieving admin column and going through every value and printing the link whenever it matches.

Don't you think your query would be something like with a unique key plus you need to only check once instead of while loop

```
$query="SELECT admin FROM `$table_members` where id='uniqueid'";
```

or

```
$query="SELECT admin FROM `$table_members` where userID_email='uniqueid'";
$result=mysqli_query($connect, $query);
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result); // see if match found
if($row_cnt>0) { // if false mean unknown user
   $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $admin = $row['admin'];
    if ($admin=="Administrator") {
        echo "<a href=\"admin.php\">Admin Panel</a>";
    }
    else {
        echo "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked, only that I made the email being identified as a logged in user. :D

Answer (score 0):

First of all your connection is problem

1)remove all double quotes in mysqli_connection parameters .your passing variable as parameter if you give double quotes it treated as string so remove double quotes

```
    $connect=mysqli_connect($db_server, $db_user, $db_password, $db_database);
    $query="SELECT admin FROM `$table_members` where email='user email address' ";
    $result=mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $admin = $row['admin'];
        if ($admin=="Administrator") {
            echo "<a href=\"admin.php\">Admin Panel</a>";
        }
        else {
            echo "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I got it working by identifying the email on `WHERE email` as a logged in user. :)